# ADF Copy only when a new CSV file is placed in the source and copy to the Container

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-adf

I want to copy the file from Source to target container but only when the Source file is new
(latest file is placed in source). I am not sure how to proceed this and not sure about the syntax to check the source file greater than target. Should i have to use two get metadata activity to check source and target last modified date and use if condition. i tried few ways but it didn't work.
Any help will be handy

[image]

syntax i used for the condition is giving me the error

@if(greaterOrEquals(ticks(activity('Get Metadata_File').output.lastModified),activity('Get Metadata_File2')),True,False)

error message

The function 'greaterOrEquals' expects all of its parameters to be either integer or decimal numbers. Found invalid parameter types: 'Object'

Comment: Also refer to one my answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68560714/15969417) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69551445/15969417)

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i tried it out but the problem is folder path and directory are static, i have three different environments and how would i change the variable in the folder source path from (DEV/TEST/PROD) dynamically. Thats why i though of using the condition if container file is older than source file then copy or else don't copy but syntax is not working properly and i tried to change the syntax to the following @if(less(ticks(activity('Get Metadata_File').output.lastModified),ticks(adddays(utcnow(),0))),True,False) this works but not expected behaviour

Comment: I figured out where the syntax was going wrong, Fixed the syntax and got the right results @if(less(ticks(activity('Get Metadata_File').output.lastModified),ticks(activity('Get Metadata_File2').output.lastmodified)),True,False)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try one of the Pipeline Templates that ADF offers.

[image]

[image]

> Use this template to copy new and changed files only by using
> LastModifiedDate. This template first selects the new and changed
> files only by their attributes "LastModifiedDate", and then copies
> them from the data source store to the data destination store. You can
> also go to "Copy Data Tool" to get the pipeline for the same scenario
> with more connectors.
>
> [View
> documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/solution-template-copy-new-files-lastmodifieddate)

### OR...

You can use **Storage Event Triggers** to trigger the pipeline with copy activity to  copy when each new file is written to storage.

Follow detailed example here: [Create a trigger that runs a pipeline in response to a storage event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-create-event-trigger?tabs=data-factory)